# SSD persistent disk as boot disk for datalab instance

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I would like to use a SSD persistent disk as a boot disk for a google cloud datalab instance.
With the datalab create command it is not possible to choose a disk type. Is there any other way?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that it's not exposed as an option.

If you want to do this quickly you could create your own version of the create command, which is on github:
https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/blob/master/tools/cli/commands/create.py#L685

Otherwise I've created https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1847 to track this.